# boundary value problem with shooting method runge kutta

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have to solve this **boundary value problem** for

$$ y''(x) -x \ y(x) = 0  \\
 y(a) = y_a \\  y(b)=y_b $$

for some $y_a$ and $y_b$. I have to use the *Shooting method* with *Runge–Kutta 4*.

So far I have

$$ 
z_1(x)=y(x) \\
z_2(x)=y'(x)
$$
from which I get:
$$
z_1'(x)=z_2(x) \\
z_2'(x)=x\ z_1(x)
$$

And this is where it stops. What am I missing to have a full system of equations that I'll solve with Rk4? And how do I get the parameter $\alpha$ that I will have to tune?

Sorry if the question isn't well formed, but I am still quite lost here. I have looked at some other questions about shooting method but the answers just confuse me even more (it may be just because of the late hour), so a simple answer or a hint would be nice.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can go through the examples here first and get your hands around the setup before moving the RK4 part, since this is a rather involved algorithm with a lot of steps. See: http://mcs.cankaya.edu.tr/proje/2010/guz/kamilyucel/rapor.pdf

Comment: @Amzoti, the link is broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have converted the problem into a system of two differential equations.

Now you need to set it up as a Initial Value Problem (IVP). This means you need to specify the initial values for $z_1(a)$ and $z_2(a)$. We know that $z_1(a) = y_a$, but we need to `guess' $z_2(a)$. This guess is your parameter $\alpha$.

The shooting method involves repeatedly solving this IVP problem (using RK4) over the interval $[a, b]$ with different values of $\alpha$. You then compare the computed value of $z_1(b)$ against $y_b$.

**The aim is to find the value of $\alpha$ that gives the result $z_1(b) = y_b$ to the required accuracy.**

A simple (but not efficient) way to do this is to find two values of $\alpha$ that bracket the value $y_b$ and then use the bisection method to refine the approximation.